# Compute the normalisation of $\mathbb{C}[X^3,XY^2,Y^3]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm pretty sure the answer should be $\mathbb{C}[X^3,XY^2, X^2Y, Y^3]$. This guess comes from the fact $X^2Y$ is integral (it's the root of $t-\frac{X^3 Y^3}{XY^2}$) and some pretty sketchy geometric reasoning.

I know how to compute normalisations of curves but the same techniques don't seem to apply.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct.

To begin, observe that $R=\Bbb C[X^3,X^2Y,XY^2,Y^3]$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions $K=\Bbb C(X^3,X^2Y,XY^2,Y^3)$: viewing $R$ as a subring of $\Bbb C[X,Y]$ and using that $\Bbb C[X,Y]$ is integrally closed in $\Bbb C(X,Y)$, we see that any polynomial with coefficients from $R$ which is satisfied by an element of $K$ must be satisfied by an element in $\Bbb C[X,Y]\cap K=R$.

This implies the integral closure of $\Bbb C[X^3,XY^2,Y^3]$ is a subring of $R$. But as you've noted, the integral closure contains $X^2Y$ and therefore must actually be all of $R$.

Comment: I'm not sure why the first part of your argument doesn't apply to $A = \mathbb{C}[X^3,X^2Y,Y^3]$ and $k = \mathbb{C}(X^3,X^2Y,Y^3)$ to show that $A$ is integrally closed in $k$.

Comment: The full claim would be "for any integrally closed graded domain, any Veronese subring is again integrally closed in its field of fractions". $A$ is not a Veronese subring of an integrally closed graded domain, $R$ is.